# How to create task with event trigger in windows Task Scheduler through command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have the below code in a batch file, which if double clicked will create a task ***TimeLogger*** in task scheduler which will execute ***start.vbs*** file on ***16:50*** on every day from monday to friday

```
SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN "TimeLogger" /TR "%cd%\start.vbs" /ST 16:15
```

I am doing this via command promt because i want to send it to my peers, who can just double click the file to create this task.

But I need to modify the task so that it will be triggered by an Event (Event it 20225).I am able to create this from task scheduler UI, but how ill i do this from cmd, so i can make it into a batch file?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
schtasks /Create ^
  /SC Onevent ^
  /MO "*[Application/EventID=20225]" ^ 
  /EC Application ^
  /TN "TimeLogger" ^
  /TR "start.vbs" ^
  /F
```

[Schtasks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490996(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Will the EventID be same everytime? Or can it vary? (This event id 20225 happens when i do a vpn connection to my office network)

Comment: Track it In event viewer